# Docker - secure mysql configuration

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to make a separate docker container for mine `mysql` database which will run for my production and test environment. The problem is that it has the potential to exposes the `port` number and environment values to for example hackers who have gained access to the container.

How can I write a secure `mysql` image that doesn't show the port number and environment variables?

**UPDATE**

I have created a local .env file and used variables in mine docker-compose.yml.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
     - 3306
    environment:
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: Honestly, if someone is able to access the container in this manner, you have much bigger problems to worry about! You should treat the security of your containers and the host they run on as seriously as if it were any stand-alone server.

Comment: @locksem You're right, the location of a docker-compose is not in the container but on the host server. So, it's  in a secure location. At least now I have centralized the source location. Thank you for your reply.